# ios5 presentmodalviewcontroller multiple views

Tags: ios5, xcode4

i made an app with there views via presentModalViewController.

the first view is ViewController.m

```
#import "secondview.h"
- (IBAction)pushme:(id)sender {    
    secondview *second = [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];    
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];}
```

the second view is secondview.m

```
#import "thirdview.h"
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender {    
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
-(IBAction)gohead:(id)sender{    
    thirdview *third = [[thirdview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];    
    [self presentModalViewController:third animated:YES];}
```

the third view is thirdview.m

```
- (IBAction)backtomain:(id)sender {    
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
```

my question is that when i click the button (backtomain) in third view, i want to go back first view, not second view.  so how can i organize backtomain function ?

thanks ~

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following steps.

1. store a reference of third view controller in the second.

   @property (nonatomic, strong) secondview *modalV;
   -(IBAction)pushme:(id)sender
   {
       secondview *second = [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
       self.modalV = second;
       [second release];
       [self presentModalViewController:modalV animated:YES];
   }

2.Set up a protocol in the third view controller that sends a message when you press "backToMain"

Then in second view controller, handle the message

```
- (void) backToMain
{
    if(self.modalV)
    {
        [modalV dismissModal]; // define this in third
        [modalV release];
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // it will dismiss second
}
```

In third

```
- (void) dismissModal
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
}
```

Comment: hi , i am a beginner, so i can not understand your code well, here is my file: http://www.tempfiles.net/download/201203/232758/delay-actions.html, could you check it please ?